# Sending list of fragments to FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

im trying to make my FragmentPagerAdapter implementation reusable by sending list of fragments to pager adpater.

```
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
Fragment fragment = mFragmentList.get(position);
    if (fragment==null)
    {
      fragment=Fragment.instantiate(mContext,fragmentName????)
    }
}
```

Pager adapter dont uses fragment manager so tag is not defined there.
Solution may be to  specify fragments tag in xml but i would like to keep managing my fragments dynamically.
Guess answer is in properly implementing inheritance...
Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the documentation for `Fragment.instantiate` [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#instantiate(android.content.Context, java.lang.String, android.os.Bundle)), you'll see that the fragment name is not the same as the fragment's tag. It's the name of the class of your fragment. So if your fragment class is `MyCustomFragment`, you would create it using the following:

`Fragment.instantiate(mContext, MyCustomFragment.class.getName());`

But, generally best practice is to use a static `newInstance` method for fragment creation. You can read more on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment).